# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation SBS 2011 reset search index

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How do you reset the search index in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation runing on SBS 2011?

I have out of date results in the search which don't exist any more.

Doing a full crawl doesn't seem to remove them

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your sharepoint central administration and then Manage Service Applications > Search Service Application > Index Reset (on the left nav under crawling).

This looks like what you are looking for.

> "Resetting the crawled content will erase the content index. After a reset, search results will not be available until crawls have been run. 
>   It is recommended that you deactivate search alerts during the reset so as to prevent alerts subscribers from receiving unwanted e-mail."